# How to build the latest Android SignApk from source?

Tags: android

I'd like to build the latest Android [SignApk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/master/tools/signapk/) from source to sign OTA updates. What are the required libraries and tools (JDK version, etc.) to build it?

Some libraries I found in the wild:

- [apksig](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/refs/heads/master)
- [Bouncy Castle](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bouncycastle/+/refs/heads/master)

P.S
As a newbie, I would be needing some simple instructions.

Regards

---

### EDIT

For now, I used the old SignApk single class file:

- [53e104e78c13d616a073c62a37ffdf18d25db2df](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/53e104e78c13d616a073c62a37ffdf18d25db2df)

This is the last commit that only requires the old Sun API (just before they replaced it with Bouncy Castle).

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with JDK versions etc...

These below steps are required to build signed APK.

Goto Build -->Generate signed Bubdle/APK -->selct APK -->
Enter module
Enter Key store path ( this is the jks file selct correct path to store the jks sile)
Enter Alias Password ( save these password )
Enter Certificate Details.

-->Click Next -->
select Build Variants 1.Debug 2.Release
we need to select Debug option

-->then select signature versions 1. V1 (jar signature) 2. v2 (Full APK Signature)

--> click finish -->

Apk will generate

Comment: I believe this is not what the OP was asking. The question relates to building the signing tool from source.